# How can I setup webhook secret on Ubuntu webhook commad?

Tags: json, ubuntu, github, webhooks

Details are given below.

```
apt-get install webhook
vim hooks.json
----------:
[
{
    "id": "plan",
     "execute-command": "/opt/hooks.com/hooks.sh",
     "command-working-directory": "/opt/plan",
     "response-message": "Webhook is rebuilding"
},
----------:
```

```
webhook -port 9500 -hooks hooks.json -verbose -hotreload -ip 10.128.22.125
```

Here hook URL is `https://hooks.com/hooks/plan`

This will trigger the hook and execute bash script on given directory. I am calling this webhook URL from GitHub to trigger on push events. I would like to add secrets to this webhook to ensure security when calling from hook URL. Please help me to setup secrets token with this webhook.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution here https://github.com/adnanh/webhook/blob/master/docs/Hook-Rules.md

```
vim hooks.json
```

and put in the following content:

```
[
{
    "id": "plan",
    "execute-command": "/opt/hooks.com/hooks.sh",
    "command-working-directory": "/opt/plan",
    "response-message": "Webhook is rebuilding"
    "trigger-rule":
    {
      "and":
      [
        {
          "match":
          {
            "type": "payload-hash-sha1",
            "secret": "yourSecretToken",
            "parameter":
            {
              "source": "header",
              "name": "X-Hub-Signature"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
   }
]
```